# Can't delete the links anymore from FB

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am currently working on an app that removes the links that you posted on Facebook from the app after you want to delete some published stuff in the app.

Yesterday everything worked.

Today when i try to delete any links shared on Facebook i receive the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 1
    }
}
```

The user gave the permission to `read_stream` and `publish_actions`.

I also tried the same thing in Graph Explorer Tool provided by Facebook and the same error occurs, while yesterday everything was fine.

I do not know what happened. If can someone illuminate me i will be forever grateful.

UPDATE with code:

```
/**
 * @param {!function(string):boolean} filter
 * @param {Function} callback
 */
findRemoveFBposts = function(filter, callback) {
    var IDS = [];
    var removeLinks = function(index) {
        FB.api(IDS[index], "DELETE", function(response) {
            ++index < IDS.length ? removeLinks(index) : (callback && callback(IDS));
        });
    };
    var fetchFB = function(query) {
        FB.api(query, function(response) {
            if (!response['error']) {
                for (var i = 0, n = response['data'].length; i < n; i += 1) {
                    filter(response['data'][i]['link']) && IDS.push(response['data'][i]['id']);
                }
                response['paging'] && response['paging']['next'] ? fetchFB(response['paging']['next']) : (IDS.length ? removeLinks(0) : (callback && callback(IDS)));
            } else {
                IDS.length ? removeLinks(0) : (callback && callback(IDS));
            }
        });
    };
    fetchFB("/v2.0/me/links?fields=link");
};

findRemoveFBposts(function(link) {
    return link=='http://mywebsite.com/somepost';
}, function() {
    console.log('Everything is done')
});
```

EDIT:

This was a feature that was exploiting a Facebook security issue. The correct way to do it is in Patrick's answer.

Comment: _"after you want to delete your account."_ well if the user has deleted their account they have no credentials as they no longer have an account...

Comment: The point is that the user will not be deleted until the clean-up finishes. Please try to understand that this is a Facebook related question and not a mistake in the code. :D Yesterday worked, today no more. If someone could tell me if FB has changed something overnight i would be glad.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I have updated the question to not be misleading anymore.

Comment: Do you mean an account with you, or their account on facebook?

Comment: @PatrickEvans Their account. They login in the app and they trigger the deletion process. It is under the users profile.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I have updated with a piece of code for you to better understand.

Comment: The only thing i can think of is you are not using a long lived access token, or have not gotten a fresh access token before calling the delete api

Comment: @PatrickEvans Can you try yourself in the Graph Explorer Tool ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this probably is happening because your app did not post the item you are trying to delete. You need to check that it was your app that actually made the post

The post should have an application object (if it was posted an app, otherwise it wont exist at all) with the app info to check against in the data returned about the post

```
{
   //...
   "application": {
      "name": "Graph API Explorer",
      "id": "145634995501895"
   },
   //...
}
```

So you could do

```
//Either the post was not created by an app
//or was not created by your app
if(response['data'][i].application === undefined || response['data'][i].application.id != "your app id") {
   return;
}
```

Comment: One thing i can't understand. How can i remove the links if the user shared by copy pasting the URL in FB. That way the share is not from the app itself but i want to remove those posts also. And also why did this work yesterday and today doesn't anymore ?

Comment: You cannot remove them if your app did not post them, there is no way around that(unless there is an extra permission that allows it, not familiar with all of the permissions just their most used ones so), its a security feature, otherwise apps could delete any post at anytime. As for why it worked yestarday, maybe they didnt have a copy/pasted link in their posts yestarday and today they do

Comment: At first i thought exactly the same, but i found that it worked like showed in the code up until yesterday. The issue is that the links shared via FB.ui from the app will not show up in the me/links.

Comment: Ok. it seems we made a feature based on a Facebook security issue in the api that was fixed. Thank you for your help.